# Property 'xxx' not found on object of type 'yyy'

Tags: ios, xcode4

I upgraded to xcode 4.0 and am now getting this error when I compile:

"Property 'xxx' not found on object of type 'yyy'"

where xxx is a property and yyy is my delegate.

I'm trying to set the property xxx on the delegate object as follows:

```
self.delegate.xxx=@"abc"
```

Does anyone know why this would not be working now with xcode 4.0?  It was fine with xcode 3.x.

I'm also getting this compile error:

"Expression is no assignable - type of receiver is unknown"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your delegate is of type id? If so, the compiler doesn't have enough information to safely let you do this.  You need to cast your delegate to a type that is expecting to have a property xxx.  I also find . notation more warning-prone.  Maybe something like this:

```
[(YourObj *)self.delegate setXXX:@"abc"];
```

Comment: Darren...Yes my delegate is of type id.  That did the trick!  Thanks so much for the fast response.